# ¿Cómo puedo saber si el scanner del teclado es una barra espaciadora?

Tags: java, string, scanner

He estado intentando con un Scanner en java ver en una sentencia if si la entrada es una barra espaciadora, he estado intentando con equals(" "), con .isBlank(), .isEmpty(), pero no.

```
Scanner m = new Scanner(System.in);
mensaje=m.next();
if(mensaje.equals(" ")){
      System.out.println("Vacio");
}
```

Pero nunca entra al ciclo.

Comment: `if` no es un ciclo. Es una rama. `while` si es un ciclo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una diferencia que aplica a tu problema entre el método next y nextLine es la siguiente

**Next()**

Deja de leer la entrada cuando encuentra espacio.
**NextLine()**

Deja de leer la entrada cuando encuentra '\n' o presiona enter.

Basado en esa diferencia lo correcto seria usar NextLine() y obtener el espacio de la siguiente manera

*si la entrada es un espacio al dar enter capturara ese valor y si es igual a un espacio imprimira vacio*

```
char c=m.nextLine().charAt(0);
System.out.println(c);

if(c==' '){
      System.out.println("Vacio");
}
```